# ValueError: in user code using CNN saved model

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, joblib

While loading CNN Saved model with tensorflow "from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model" than an error occur:
Error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2169, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2155, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2143, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2111, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 253, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 800)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("DeserializeSparse:1", shape=(None,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("stack:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

My code is:

```
TF_IDF_Apply = joblib.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/Preprocessing/TFIDF_Applied1.csv")
Linear_SVC_classifier = joblib.load("path/model_cnn.sav")
test_data=vector.transform(datainput)
n=Linear_SVC_classifier.predict(test_data)
print(n)
```

Variable "TF_IDF_Apply" has same no of features as that of training but an error is occured.

i am actually using a saved cnn model but an error is occuring. Is there a way to remove this error? I do this but when i open my google colab notebook than the CNN model is not working and all the previouse files are not handled successfuly.